# Are these spaces quotient spaces?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm having trouble with this question:

> Consider the following spaces:
>
> 1. Two circles of radius $1$ that are centered at $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ (so that they touch at the origin - forming a "figure eight") with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f$ be any continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to this space. Can $f$ be a quotient map?
> 2. Consider the two sets $X$ and $Y$, equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ below. Are they quotient spaces of the real line?

[image]

I'm not sure even where to start. What should I be looking for here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Can $f:\infty\to\mathbb{R}$ be a quotient map? Well, $\infty$ is compact, $f$ is continuous. Can it be onto?

I denote by $\infty$ the union of the two circles.

Comment: oye: image of compact spaces are compact. by hiene-borel these are closed and bounded sets in the usual top of $\mathbb{R}$. so $f$ can't be onto. what about $X$ and $Y$? following your thinking, i think quotient maps will fail here because of connectedness considerations. In particular, removing the middle point from $X$ or $Y$ will leave 3 pieces but removing a point from $R$ will leave two restrictions of continuous functions are continuous, but evidently, any continuous function with the one point restriction (mentioned above) - cannot exist becuase cts fxn preserve components. correct?

Comment: moreover, was this question even about quotient maps?

Comment: @yoshi you have considered $f:R\rightarrow figre-eight$ in your question.

Comment: @UserS im assuming you mean $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \text{ figure 8}$. if so, I haven't. 1. Could you elaborate on why I should? 2. This maps won't be continuous because removing a point off the "top of the 8" will leave 1 connected component but removing a anywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ will leave 2 connected components.

Comment: wait now I am confused. the circle is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}$. but the former is compact and the latter is not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that quotient maps are surjective so if you consider the continuous map $ f:R\rightarrow S^1\lor S^1$ given by $f(t)=e^{2\pi \iota t}+(1,0)$ is not surjective. Also constant map can also do this work.( Note also any continuous map $g:S^1\lor S^1\rightarrow R$ can not be surjective, since continuous image of compact set is compact, hence $g$ can not be quotient map)

Next $X$ is a quotient space of $R$ if you consider the partition of $R$ (any partition give raise to a equivalence relation, hence generates a  quotient space) given by $$\{[1,\infty);(\infty,-1];\{x\};\{y\};\{z,-z\}\ | x\in (-1,-\frac{1}{2}); y\in (\frac{1}{2},1);z\in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\}$$

Similarly $Y $ is also a quotient space of $R$ if we consider the partition of $R$ given by $$\{[1,\infty);(\infty,-1];\{x\};\{y\};\{z\}\ \{\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\}|x\in (-1,-\frac{1}{2}); y\in (\frac{1}{2},1); z\in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\}$$

Note in both cases $[1,\infty)$,$(\infty,-1]$ are identified to two distinct points.We have used another idea to generate $Y$ ,namely if two endpoints of a closed-bounded interval of $R$ are identified then it is homeomorphic to $S^1$.